# Cardboard Library - ZTE phone, cannot display fullscreen

Tags: java, android, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

I am trying to run the Cardboard Example on ZTE (Axon Mini B2016), but the screen is not displaying fullscreen, just a part of screen at bottom. (refer to photo for more detail).

https://github.com/googlesamples/cardboard-java

[image]

P/S: This problem doesn't happened in other model phone (Samsung, Sony).

Anyone met this problem, pls suggest me an idea, will be a big appreciation.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem to on my zte. I have another way, maybe can help. just active 3 dot overflow on your setting - accesibility - magnification gesture.